# 434MHz Noise Sources

Tags: rf, radio, noise

Are there common sources of 434MHz noise or interference in a residential/household environment? I've been playing with some radios, and they seem to be behaving flakily at my friend's house even at close range, and working flawlessly at my house... I'm a bit stumped.

I suppose another possibility is some kind of crazy noise on the wall power at my friend's place, but I'll have to try out a battery power source on the receiver to rule that out, and can post back once I do.

Unfortunately, I don't own or have access to a spectral analyzer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be a lot of devices operating in the 433 MHz band. Many cheap radio devices (like wireless thermometers and stuff) operate on 433 MHz.

The house construction could have something to do with this as well. Did you try testing it outside (with a line-of-sight) near his house?

Comment: my first thought was if it was a steel based house, some people have them, radios love them.

Answer (score 2):

PC video cards can generate a lot of hash in the 70cm band.  I've found that to be a problem in my home if the wife is playing video games.